# Shawdomere died and I can't get him back

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My story is a little different. I had Shadowmere and I believe he died during the fight at the first Dark Brotherhood sanctuary. I have waited many days and gone back but he is not there. He also hasn't re-spawned at my location.

Comment: Did you try fast traveling?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [wiki page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shadowmere), Shadowmere is supposed to re-spawn after ten days if he dies. If you have not waited this long, try waiting a few more days and going back there to see if he has re-spawned.

Unfortunately, the [wiki page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shadowmere) also notes that there is a known bug where Shadowmere may not re-spawn upon dying, in which case you're out of luck.

If you're playing on PC there are some console commands that may get him back if he's lost and not completely de-spawned: `prid 0009CCD8` will target Shadowmere wherever he is in the world and `moveto player` will then teleport your target to your location.